# Can't pull .attr() from button generated via handlebars

Tags: javascript, express, mongoose, handlebars.js, express-handlebars

I'm in the process of building a web scraper for a homework assignment involving Express, Mongoose, Cheerio/axios, and Handlebars. My "/" route grabs the Mongoose objects and handlebars loads them to the page in individual cards. A save button is generated with an attribute `data-id={{_id}}'` in these cards. I'm trying to access the attribute with jQuery when it's pressed to save it to another collection but $(this) is returning undefined.

js

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#artDiv").on("click", ".save", (event) => {
            event.preventDefault();
            let id = $(this).attr("data-id");

            console.log($(this).data("id"));
            console.log(id);        
        })
    });
```

html

```
 <div id="artDiv" class="container">
  {{#obj}}
  {{#each .}}
  {{#if headline}}
  <div id="articleCard" class="card">
    <h5 class="card-header">{{altHead}}</h5>
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">{{headline}}</h5>
      <p class="card-text">{{desc}}</p>
      <a href="{{link}}" target="_blank" class="btn btn-primary">Visit</a>
      <button data-id="{{_id}}" data-control="saveBtn" type="button" class="btn btn-success save">Save</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  {{/if}}
  {{/each}}
  {{/obj}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have your clicked element in `$(this)`, you cannot use arrow functions. You have to use `$("#artDiv").on("click", ".save", function (event) { ... });`.

Comment: Hallelujah! Thank you so much. I forgot that arrow functions are a little picky with some things.